# What's up with the Black Butler intermissions?

Tags: black-butler

Today I decided to carry on watching Black Butler since I had only watched the first episode a couple months ago and then stopped watching. (so fairly new to the series) but I noticed that every time there was an intermission or brief break in between the episode, it always seem to feature either Ceil or Sebastian next to what I think is a tarot card?

[image]
[image]

I don't mind spoilers just so you know and maybe I am a bit slow, but is there a relationship or connection between the cards and how they always pop up in intermission to the storyline etc?

Edit: I just realised that I had been watching Black Butler II and not Black Butler I which would probably be why I was confused.

Comment: from what i know of Tao Readings, when the cards are placed a card has a different meaning when it's flipped upside down, such as Death right side up means change for you while upside down Death means you'll be involved with the change of someone elses life (or be the catalyst for it).

Comment: while it isn't Death and i haven't seen it, If Ceil holding Death right side up would mean something in his life is going to change in that episode, Sebastian holding it upside down means he's going to be the cause, possible it's the same with the order cards, i don't know the meaning of Sun so i can't really tell how the images you posted my reinforce my comment

Comment: @Memor-X- So its like a hidden meaning or something indicating that somethings going to change in an episode?

Comment: Just wondering, is tao reading some kind of card reading/telling the future thing?

Comment: @アズーサthe Death Card means change, Sun is "When the Sun card shows for you, it's a sign that soon you are likely to find yourself feeling more free than you have in a while", so in your images Ceil may be more free in the episode, not sure of the inverse for Sebastian

Comment: yes, it's fortune telling, and i mean Tarot not Tao, i don't know too much of Black Butler so i can't give a proper answer but these comments may help someone else's answer

Comment: The characters and cards are loosely related to the theme/plot of the episode. It's just for flavor; they don't reveal anything not revealed in the episodes themselves.

Comment: For clarification purposes, are you asking about the meaning behind the cards or the meaning behind the all eye-catches in the second season?

Comment: @Krazer- I was wondering what was up with the opening. So I guess what the cards were related to I guess or if they shared a connection with the story in a way.

Answer (score -1):

I'm late to this, whoops.

But the tarot cards, I assume, are just a foreshadowing of the uprising events.
If the Death tarot card appears: what happens in the episode?
Well, obviously, death. Either, on Ciel's side or the opponent of Ciel.

Some other cards are harder to explain but you could search up "insert tarot card here" on Google and then find the meaning there.

Sorry if this wasn't much help. I tried!

Comment: As stated before, this site is a Q&A site. This answer might be a starting point for a good answer, but generally each post on here should be independent of external resources (even including Google). If possible, consider including the relevant tarot cards and their meaning here. As usual, you can always [edit] your post to improve it.